# Install other apps with our setup - vs2010 Desktop App Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, installation, setup-deployment

I need to embed powerpoint viewer with my setup in vs 2010.
When user run setup created by me, powerpoint viewer setup get automatically launch during installation.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Installer Class to your development

```
namespace CLT
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ClientInstall : Installer
    {
        public ClientInstall()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
                base.Install(stateSaver);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\Powerpoint.exe");
        }
}
```

And remember to add Custom actions to your setup

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for solution.. but it shows an error - error 10001 specified file not found... where should i add this powerpointviwer.exe in project..  please reply

Answer (score 3):

Usually existing packages are added as prerequisites. Visual Studio setup projects do not support custom prerequisite creation. However, this can be done by manually generating the required manifests.

You can find the manifests structure here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223(VS.80).aspx

These manifests can be generated automatically with the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=bmg) tool.

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\
```

You can then select the prerequisite in your setup project properties page.