# Adding MySQL in bootstrapper

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, setup-project

While making setup file, we can add SQL Server Express as pre-req so setup installs that first.
How to do the same with MySQL?  I want my application to install MySQL if not installed on the target PC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio doesn't have a predefined prerequisite for MySQL, a solution is to manually add the prerequisite. You can find more details here:
[Install other apps with our setup - vs2010 Desktop App Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025384/install-other-apps-with-our-setup-vs2010-desktop-app-deployment/10027397#10027397)