# Creating a setup in visual studio 10

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have made a project in Visual studio 10 that uses **Mysql database and Crystalreports** along with

it. But i dont know how to make a setup that will automatically install Mysql and Crystalreports

along with the project setup on the pc on which this project is installed.I am able to create a

simple project containg only project but it did not contain the Mysql or crystalreports setup.How

can i create such a setup that automatically installs crystal reports Mysql and the project

please refer any tutorial.

Comment: Search in google Visual Studio 2010 Setup Prerequisit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that create a `Setup and Deployment Project`. In the project prerequisites you have to include `Crystal Reports` and `MySQL`. If they are not there in the prerequisites list then i am afraid that you have to create your own bootstrapper program to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a little different problem. You can't install a whole different system along with your code. The user needs to install MySQL first and then you can run a query that creates the database inside of it. I think this needs to be done separately. In the end, you have to write script that creates the database structures after the MySQL has been installed. I don't think it can be bundled up that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Bootstrapper for this.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=bmg

See this link:

[Install other apps with our setup - vs2010 Desktop App Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025384/install-other-apps-with-our-setup-vs2010-desktop-app-deployment/10027397#10027397)

This article may help you too:

http://murrayon.net/2009/11/custom-setup-bootstrappers.html